# Workaround for - Hibernate is not supporting batch insertion when using IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Workaround  for - Hibernate is not supporting batch insertion when using IDENTITY

---

For my app, I am using SpringBoot and SQL Server. I am having a big number of data that I need to insert to the database.

Both corresponding entities (Many-To-One relationship) for the insert defined with GenerationType.IDENTITY

```
@Entity
public class DailyExportContent {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "Id")
 private Integer id;
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "DailyExportContent2DailyExport", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = 
 "FK_DailyExportContent_DailyExport"))
 private DailyExport dailyExport;


@Entity
public class DailyExport {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "Id")
 private Integer id;
```

Per my understanding, Hibernate is not supporting batch insertion when using IDENTITY.

> Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if
> you use an identity identifier generator.

Are there any generic workaround beside of removing the IDENTITY?

Comment: Not unless there is a way to figure out what the ID values assigned was when batching if using IDENTITY. Preallocation is better for that reason. Some drivers/DBs support it, but I do not believe SQL-server is one.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.